# Formatting time in SQL as day.hour

Tags: datetime, stored-procedures, time, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services

I'm creating a report from a stored procedure that pulls two date/times (CreatedDate and ClosedDate).  I need a column on the report that shows the difference (i.e. time it took to go from open to close).  First, I just subtracted CreatedDate from ClosedDate (in the report [SQL Server Reporting Services], not in the stored procedure) and got a time that looks like this: 72.20:34:18.6230000 (day.hour:minute:second).  I need to shrink this down, if possible, to just day.hour...

I was experimenting with some of the functions found on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).  DATEDIFF almost gives me what I need, but I can only specify days or hours, and ideally (as I said), I need it to show the 'time to close' as both (day.hour).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS, you can apply a custom format to that column to show only days.hours. Right click the column in design mode -->text box properties-->Number(on left hand side). If you don't see one of the formats for date, time or number that fits what you need, create a custom one at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

- Convert to minutes
- divide by 1440 gives whole days
- modulo 1440 gives remaining minutes, divide by 60 for hours

Something like (not tested):

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, ClosedDate) / 1440 AS varchar(20)) + '.'
    CAST((DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, ClosedDate) % 1440) / 60 AS varchar(20))
FROM
    MyTable
```

You may need to fiddle with the hours representation in cade I've misunderstood

DATEDIFF for day and hour go by boundaries: that is if there are just 3 minutes between the 2 values spanning midnight, there will be one hour/day difference. So I used minutes

**Edit:**

To overflow the int from DATEDIFF requires a difference of 4000+ years

Thoughts:

- Using datetime2 and have CreatedDate of lowest `0001-01-01`
- ClosedDate is a sentinel value like `9999-12-31` say for "open" items
- CreatedDate and ClosedDate are varchar and conversion to datetime is faulty

Your example shows 72 days difference which would be around 104k minutes.

I would try this to see where you have more than 1000 year differences which would be a mere half billion or so minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM mytables
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, CreatedDate, ClosedDate) > 1000
```

Comment: @gbn, executing the stored procedure results in an error: "Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime."  It looks like this is typically because it's exceeding the integer range for that time measurement.  I thought at first it was because of the combination of expressions, but I tried with only half of the expression, and it still failed.  Any ideas?  Is there a way to shrink it down further before performing the CAST/DATEDIFF?

Comment: @gbn (DATEDIFF(minute, j.CreatedDate, mp.ClosedDate) / 1440) + '.' + ((DATEDIFF(minute, j.CreatedDate, mp.ClosedDate) % 1440) / 60) results in "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type int."

Comment: Sorry, I meant a single datediff. This gives Int and 2 billion minutes is 4000 years so of course

Comment: @gbn, the requirements ended up changing (he just wanted it formatted in hours), so I didn't end up using this, but thank you for your suggestions.